# Square all the numbers at an array's odd indices

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to square all the integers at odd indices so that I can add up the whole array later. This is where I am so far:

```
function verryNiceFunc(arr) {
    var x = arr.filter(function(num) {
        if (num % 2) return num;
    }).reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
      return previousValue + currentValue;
    });
    var y = arr.filter(function(num) {
        if (num % 2 != 1) return num;
    }).reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
      return (currentValue * currentValue);
    });
    console.log(y);
    return x + y;
}

verryNiceFunc([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]);
//Should return 376
```

As you can see, var y needs a little editing. Think I need a for loop but not sure how to get it done.

http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/xez8obd3/11/

Comment: my head hurts now lol. i tried i guess.

Comment: Is that my voice speaking?

Comment: I must notice that you want elements at odd *indices* squared, but you're actually checking if the *numbers* are odd in your `filter` callbacks.  Watch out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it. Just one `reduce` operation with an odd/even switch in the callback function body:

```js
var values = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var result = values.reduce(function(result, value, i) {
  return result += (i % 2 ? value * value : value);
}, 0);

alert(result);
```

Comment: Initialization value for the `result`. Maybe not strictly needed, but makes things clear. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Right gonna fiddle with that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

[Robby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31872139/714240) is good enough, but if you want to speed things up a bit, you can always rely on a classic `for` cycle:

```
for (var i = 0, sum = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    sum += i & 1 ? arr[i] * arr[i] : arr[i];
```